# How to install OctoberCMS on Centos?

Tags: centos, backend, mamp, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I have a ready-made cms that I developed on Windows and opened through the `OpenServer` and `MAMP`. On Windows, everything opens and works fine. When I transferred the directory to the centos (`/var/www/cms`), seted the root document in the Apache, transferred the `mysql` database, installed the necessary version of `php` I started getting some errors. It seems to me that I might have set the configs wrong, or in general, what could it be?

```
[Wed Feb 10 09:10:24.886644 2021] [php7:error] [pid 29933] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Cms\\Classes\\Router::__construct() must be an instance of Cms\\Classes\\Theme, null given, called in /var/www/cms/modules/system/classes/ErrorHandler.php on line 62 and defined in /var/www/cms/modules/cms/classes/Router.php:67\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/cms/modules/system/classes/ErrorHandler.php(62): Cms\\Classes\\Router->__construct()\n#1 /var/www/cms/vendor/october/rain/src/Exception/ErrorHandler.php(56): System\\Classes\\ErrorHandler->handleCustomError()\n#2 /var/www/cms/modules/system/ServiceProvider.php(276): October\\Rain\\Exception\\ErrorHandler->handleException()\n#3 [internal function]: System\\ServiceProvider->System\\{closure}()\n#4 /var/www/cms/vendor/october/rain/src/Events/Dispatcher.php(233): call_user_func_array()\n#5 /var/www/cms/vendor/october/rain/src/Events/Dispatcher.php(197): October\\Rain\\Events\\Dispatcher->dispatch()\n#6 /var/www/cms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(221): October\\Rain\\Events\\Dispatcher->fire()\n#7 /var/www/cms/vendo in /var/www/cms/modules/cms/classes/Router.php on line 67
```

Comment: what PHP version are you using can you share details?

Comment: @HardikSatasiya on Windows where everything worked, the version was used - `7.3.9`,  on centos - `7.4.14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to install all the libraries, this command helped me (on `centos 7`)

`yum -y install php70w php70w-mysql php70w-dom php70w-xml php70w-gd php70w-fileinfo php70w-curl php70w-mcrypt php70w-zip php70w-mbstring`